# Device Token Generation and Dispersal for push notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Is there any possibility of device token for push notification getting changed when upgrading the ios version from 6.0 to 6.1 or 7.0.1 to 7.0.4

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW12 check for more detail

Answer (score 1):

Device token are a unique identifier for an app installed on a phone. If you delete an app and reinstall it on the same phone, the device token will be the same. 
So software version doesn't change the token.

Comment: It should be the same on reinstall, but it does not have to be the same. Just be aware of this. A device token for push notification can change and you should always check this on startup and update the token if needed.

Comment: I never noticed token changes in my apps. I have test mode for notifications with token manually registered. It's always the same on an app, even with software updates. But you're right to check it at app launch to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any possibility of device token for push notification getting changed when upgrading the ios version from 6.0 to 6.1 or 7.0.1 to 7.0.4

The answer is No, it will not change when upgrading iOS.

> So how could the token possibly change ?

The device token would change if you ever reset the phone to default.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the device token changes when you upgrade the iOS version. I experienced it in older iOS versions.

In addition,  I read that from iOS 7 different apps on the same device get different device tokens, which wasn't the case in iOS 6 and older versions.